# Story board for smooth touch scroll in WPF

Tags: c, wpf

Please provide storyboard for smooth touch scrolling for tablet in wpf. In my case touch response is not smooth and is shifting like it is going to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

No need for storyBoard...
just add scrollviewer to your code

```
<ScrollViewer 
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" PanningMode="Both"  ManipulationBoundaryFeedback="ScrollViewerCanvas_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback">
    //Add stuff here
</ScrollViewer>
```

in codeBehind:

```
private void ScrollViewerCanvas_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback(object sender, ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: I am scrolling list by touch screen. It's working or not? And i have no scroll viewer from other . I am enabling scrolling in TileList.

Comment: And we have required only HorizontalScrollBarVisibility not verticle.

Comment: selectionChange event does not work of Tile List when i am using above code.

Comment: Your question is unclear add some detail to it ..show your code atleast

Comment: I have telerik Tile List and i want to smooth touch scrolling. And when we are are using your code then selectionChange event does not work of tile list. Okey.